# How to dynamically select class type when parsing JSON to object in Play Framework?

Tags: scala, playframework

The following sample code uses Play Framework to parse JSON to an object:

```
  def createEvent(): Action[JsValue] = Action.async(parse.tolerantJson) {
    request => {
      request.body.validate[SomeEvent] match {
        case o:JsSuccess[SomeEvent] => {
          //do something
          Future(Created)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Is it possible to generalise it so it can handle different event types? e.g.

```
  def createEvent(): Action[JsValue] = Action.async(parse.tolerantJson) {
    request => {
      val eventType = request.contentType match {
        case Some("SomeEventType") => SomeEvent
        case Some("OtherEventType") => OtherEvent
      }
      request.body.validate[eventType] match {
        case o:JsSuccess[eventType] => {
          //do something
          Future(Created)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Currently, the above code will fail in the line `request.body.validate[eventType]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract `body.validate[T]` into a function and call it from your patten matching construct with a proper type, i.e:

```
def extract[T: JsonFormat](implicit req: Request[AnyContent]) = req.body.valudate[T]

request.contentType match {
  case Some("SomeEventType") => extract[SomeEvent]
  case Some("OtherEventType") => extract[OtherEvent]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, passing the type as T worked, I also ended up passing different extract methods as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can read and create class from `contentType` dynamically. But you can have problem, if will be no implicit Format for extracted type in scope:

```
error: No Json formatter found for type A. Try to implement an implicit Format for this type.
```

or

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: models.Bazz
```

The available data:

1. model

   package models

   case class Bar(name: String)
2. request

   request.contentType: Option[String] = Some("models.Bar")
3. incoming body

   request.body: JsValue = """{"name": "bar name"}"""
4. format[Bar]

   implicit val BarFormat = Json.format[models.Bar]

extractor:

```
def extract[A <: Any](ct: String, json: JsValue)(implicit format: Format[A]) = {

  val manifest:Manifest[A] = Manifest.classType[A](Class.forName(ct))

  json.validate[A]
}

request.contentType.map(extract(_, request.body))

res1: Option[play.api.libs.json.JsResult[models.Bar]] = Some(JsSuccess(Bar(bar name),/name))
```

you can see https://github.com/strongtyped/fun-cqrs/blob/demos/shop-sample/samples/shop/src/main/scala/funcqrs/json/TypedJson.scala for other way of deserializing self-contained json.